# How to filter identical named attributes of classes

Tags: code-generation, xtend

With a Xtend file, I am generating a hpp file including attributes of inputed object classes.
The following code snippet writes all attributes related to the classes.

```
«FOR o : myClass.objectClasses»
    Test::ObjectClassHandle _class_«o.fullyQualifiedName.toString("_")»;
    «FOR a : o.attributes»
        Test::AttributeHandle «_attr_«a.fullyQualifiedName.toString("_")»;
    «ENDFOR»
«ENDFOR»
```

The problem is that some classes include the same attributes. How can I filter identical named attributes so each attribute is written once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `attributes` to a map, using the attribute name as a key. 
Only one attribute is stored for each key, so all of the map's values will be attributes with unique names:

```
o.attributes.toMap[fullyQualifiedName.toString("_")].values
```